# Can I define access rights on deployment level on cloudcontrol?

Tags: deployment, rights, cloudcontrol

On my cloudcontrol app, I would like to restrict the access to the default deployment exclusively. That means I want to grant full access to all deployments, except for the default deployment. Is there a way to define access rights on deployment level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply invite the user to the deployment instead of the app like this:

```
$ cctrlapp APP_NAME/DEP_NAME user.add email@example.org
```

For details and also how to set the user's role please refer to the documentation here: https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#users